# $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{z}z =3$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{z}z^2 = 4$ in a rectangle with boundary $C$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $C$ be a positively oriented contour forming the boundary of the
>   rectangle $1\leq \text{Re}(z)\leq 4$, $-2\leq \text{Im}(z)\leq 2$. An
>   entire function $f(z)$ is known to have no zeros on $C$, and satisfies
>   the two conditions $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z =3
>  \quad\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z^2 =
>  4.$$ Determine all zeros of $f(z)$ inside the rectangle.

I can show (I think) that for $z_i$ zeros in the rectangle of order $m_i$, we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z=\sum m_i z_i \quad \text{and}\quad \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z^2=\sum m_i z_i^2.$$

This gives us $\sum m_i z_i=3$ and $\sum m_i z_i^2=4$. Some fooling around tells me that simple zeros at $\frac{3}{2}+\frac12 i$ and $\frac32 - \frac12i$ will satisfy this, but why can I claim that this is the unique such set of zeros? (Perhaps I can't, and they just want some conditions on the zeros?)

Comment: Something's wrong with your integrals. It look like you want $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z^k\,dz$$ for $k\in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the integrals are actually

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z\,dz = 3\tag{1}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}z^2\,dz = 4,\tag{2}$$

since $1 < \operatorname{Re} z_i$ for the zeros, from $(1)$, we deduce that there are only one or two zeros of $f$ in the rectangle, counted with multiplicity. If there were only one, $(1)$ tells us it's $3$, but then the integral in $(2)$ would be $3^2 = 9$, so there are two zeros. These must be distinct, since if there were a double zero, that would be $\frac32$, and the integral in $(2)$ would be $2\cdot\left(\frac32\right)^2 = \frac{9}{2} \neq 4$. So we have two distinct zeros, $z_1,\, z_2 = 3-z_1$, and it remains to solve the quadratic equation

$$w^2 + (3-w)^2 = 4.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer!